# How can I set variable values in nginx config using map?

Tags: nginx

How can I set variable values in nginx config using map (or if)?
I need to set proxy_ssl_server_name and proxy_http_version values depending on the upstream address. If the upstream address is example1, the variables take one value, if the upstream address is different, they take other values.

Below I have given a variant of my config, but for some reason nginx gives an error that the values should be specified explicitly.

It's like I'm running it without map dictives, it's like nginx doesn't see them.

```
nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:2
2024/03/07 06:24:33 [emerg] 1#1: invalid value "$ssl_value" in "proxy_ssl_server_name" directive, it must be "on" or "off" in /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/nginx.conf:25
nginx: [emerg] invalid value "$ssl_value" in "proxy_ssl_server_name" directive, it must be "on" or "off" in /opt/bitnami/nginx/nginx/conf/server_blocks/nginx.conf:25





map $upstream_addr $ssl_value {
    default       off;
    "~example2" on;
}

map $upstream_addr $http_ver_value {
    default       1.0;
    "~example1" 1.1;
}

server {
  listen 8443 ssl default_server;
  root /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/;
  index index.html;

  server_name _;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/cert;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/key;
  
  location /my-some/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location /my-test/ {
    proxy_ssl_server_name $ssl_value;
    proxy_http_version $http_ver_value;
    proxy_ssl_name $host;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass https://CnvTLSPreapprovedServiceApp;
  }

}

upstream CnvTLSPreapprovedServiceApp {
  server example1.com:443 weight=1;
  server example2.com:443 weight=4;
}
```